# Python update YAML without changing formatting

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to update a particular property in a yaml file while leaving the rest untouched, including formatting, comments etc. I'm using raumel.yaml. But when I save the file it's formatting gets messed up. I'm using python 3.9.5 and raumel.yaml Version: 0.17.10.

`test.yaml`:

```
sso:
  version: 1.0.0
  configs:
  - configName: config1.conf
    fileContent: 'startDelaySeconds: 0

      lowercaseOutputName: true

      lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false

      whitelistObjectNames: [''org.apache.commons.pool2:*'']

      blacklistObjectNames: []

      rules:

      - pattern: ".*"

      '
```

I update the version with:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
with open('test.yaml') as f:
    test = yaml.load(f)
test['sso']['version'] = '1.0.1'
with open('test2.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(test, f)
```

But the `fileContent` of the saved file is changed in format (newlines replaces by `\n` etc). `test2.yaml`:

```
sso:
  version: 1.0.1
  configs:
  - configName: config1.conf
    fileContent: "startDelaySeconds: 0\nlowercaseOutputName: true\nlowercaseOutputLabelNames:\
      \ false\nwhitelistObjectNames: ['org.apache.commons.pool2:*']\nblacklistObjectNames:\
      \ []\nrules:\n- pattern: \".*\"\n"
```

Comment: I updated your program, because what you pasted in here could never have given that output.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks, I had copied the incorrect command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably missed is that the quotes in the value
for your output changes from single to double quotes. By default `ruamel.yaml`
doesn't try to preserve quotes, thereby being able to remove any superfluous
quotes, or in this case use a more compact representation.
using double quoting that doesn't need single quotes within the scalar
to be duplicated.

You can preserve the quotes by setting the `.preserve_quotes` attribute:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
with open('test.yaml') as f:
    test = yaml.load(f)
test['sso']['version'] = '1.0.1'
yaml.dump(test, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
sso:
  version: 1.0.1
  configs:
  - configName: config1.conf
    fileContent: 'startDelaySeconds: 0

      lowercaseOutputName: true

      lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false

      whitelistObjectNames: [''org.apache.commons.pool2:*'']

      blacklistObjectNames: []

      rules:

      - pattern: ".*"

      '
```

I recommend considering using a literal style scalar for values
that contain newlines, as in those you don't need to double the newline,
nor need to double single quotes in your scalar:

```
yaml_str = """
sso:
  version: 1.0.0
  configs:
  - configName: config1.conf
    fileContent: |
      startDelaySeconds: 0
      lowercaseOutputName: true
      lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
      whitelistObjectNames: ['org.apache.commons.pool2:*']
      blacklistObjectNames: []
      rules:
      - pattern: ".*"
  
"""

import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
with open('test.yaml') as f:
    test = yaml.load(f)

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
assert data['sso']['configs'][0]['fileContent']  == test['sso']['configs'][0]['fileContent']
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, so I've accepted your answer.

One more question: By any chance is there a way to preserve indenation? Specifically some properties have a bit more indent, which is getting removed.

Ideally this shouldn't be the case but this is a shared config file used by a lot of people so I don't want to mess with other people's stuff.

Comment: You cannot preserve it on an individual basis. You can use `yaml.indent(6, 4, 2)` to have mappings indent 6 positions, and sequences 4 positions with the sequence indicator (`-`) offset two positions within that 4. Have you played with that?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, there are different indent styles within the file. Might be easier if I just try and get the indents uniform first.