# Load and modify YAML without breaking the indents?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

Hi wanted to update this integer value of `x`  to `8` but I could not get any good understanding on how can I do that without making any effect in indents inside `sub` in yaml file. I wanted to read this YAML file, replace the string to `x=8` and save the yaml file as it is.

I am using Python for the modification, here is the sample code:

```
parent:
- 
  subchild: something
  subchild2: something
    - sub: 
        y = 4; 
        x = 6 # I wanted to replace this integer to 8  
        z = 10
```

**Note Point**: `x=6` will be in multiple files, so I wanted to open files one by one, and do all the modifications ( `x=8`) and save those files one by one.

**Problem**

I was able to replace the file but what the problem I am facing is, the result becomes this:

```
parent:
- 
  subchild: something
  subchild2: something
    - sub: y = 4; x = 8; z = 10;
```

And what I want is the same indents inside `sub` as in the original yaml file. Hope you got point here.

**[EDIT] Additional information:**

This is the way I am reading the file and saving the file.

```
f = open(test.yaml, 'r')      
newf = f.read().replace('6', '8')
overrides = yaml.load(newf)
f.close()
with open('updated_test.yaml', 'w') as ff:
yaml.dump(overrides, ff)
```

Comment: PyYAML has its own conventions and is hard to bend into any other shape. I understand Ruamel is more flexible but this impression almost certainly comes from previous Stack Overflow questions about this topic. Did you search before asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519287/python-update-yaml-without-changing-formatting

Comment: I believe that it is not my answer that I am looking for specifically. I am reading each line in the yaml file and when I found a match of int value `6` I replace it with `8` with `.replace('6', '8')` and when I dump the file and save as yaml the output becomes the above one.

Comment: @tripleee, i HAVE added more information.

Comment: Try adding `default_flow_style=False` to the call to `yaml.dump`.

Comment: You are not modifying YAML because both sections that start with `parent:` are not valid YAML documents. `yaml.load()` will throw a ScannerError on both of them. So you first have to start with gettting some valid YAML (or present us with valid YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the `yaml` module for this task at all, as you aren't doing anything what it is needed for ! ;)

```py
f = open("test.yaml", 'r')      
newf = f.read().replace('6', '8')
f.close()

with open('updated_test.yaml', 'w') as ff:
    ff.write(newf)
```

Comment: Yeah! I tried, but it break the whole YAML format.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is invalid YAML, as you cannot start an indented sequence after the second `something`.
Your output is invalid as well.

If you want something like:

```
y = 4; 
x = 6 # I wanted to replace this integer to 8  
z = 10
```

in your YAML document as a multiline string, and preserve the multiple lines you
need to use `ruamel.yaml` **and** specify the string as a literal block scalar (using `|`).
And since `x = 6` is part of the string, you need to do a string replacement to
change the value. I would use a regex for that:

```
import sys
import re
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- sub: |
    y = 4; 
    x = 6 # I wanted to replace this integer to 8  
    z = 10
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
target = data[0]['sub'] 
new_value = 8
data[0]['sub'] = type(target)(re.sub('x = [0-9]*', f'x = {new_value}', target))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- sub: |
    y = 4; 
    x = 8 # I wanted to replace this integer to 8  
    z = 10
```